# Realistic cube rigid boy physics

Tags: physics

I want a scene in which a cube falls to the ground. I want this to be realistic with bounces and so on. How do I do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Simply:

- add a plane and set it to rigid body passive
- add a cube somewhat over it, set it to rigid body active
- just rotate the cube it a bit so that its bottom face is not exactly parallel to the plane... reality is never absolutely perfect. Adding to that, or otherwise, there are settings to make the plane more "bouncy" if you prefer: look under plane and cube rigid body settings and enhance "bounciness" (try 0.2- 0.4 to start for the cube, try 1 for the plane) at your taste.

Done, press <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>

[image]

Obviously the bonciness depends also on the falling object shape: try a sphere...